# Calling a framework class' from child in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, singleton, radix

Despite searching, I have not found a solution to my problem:

I am trying to subclass Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket , to make it available as a Singleton in my WP8 app:

```
     class StreamSocketSingleton : StreamSocket {

    private static StreamSocketSingleton instance;

    public StreamSocketSingleton() : base() { }

    public static StreamSocketSingleton GetInstance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new StreamSocketSingleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

So far so good. But I obviously need to call the StreamSocket functions such as ConnectAsync, GetInputStream etc.

I am trying to use the base keyword, e.g. base.ConnectAsync:

```
public void ConnectAsync(HostName hostName, String serviceName) {
base.ConnectAsync(hostName, serviceName);
}
```

Visual Studio however claims that 'object' does not contain a definition for ConnectAsync. To me, it looks like I am subclassing from Object, which I am not (right?)

Hope someone can help me out!

Cheers

Comment: Please show the code that's actually failing - i.e. the attempt to call `ConnectAsync`.

Comment: done as requested, thx

Comment: Why have you added that method at all, if it's just going to delegate to the base implementation? And is that within the `StreamSocketSingleton` class, or elsewhere?

Comment: What about making the Streamsocket available in App.xaml.cs and always reference that one? I mean, it must be possible to create / establish the connection and then reference to it from anywhere in the app. Something like an Android Service?

Comment: Honestly, I thought it was required for delegation, saw something similar in a tutorial. Delegating the method seems to be the problem here, as I said above. Problem as in it tells me 'object' does not have the implementation. 

It is indeed in the Singleton class

Comment: Well that's a completely different question, and one that it sounds like you're trying to address with the singleton anyway.

Comment: I've just noticed that `StreamSocket` is a sealed class anyway in the Windows API... so I'd expect your code to fail to compile in that respect to start with...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call the base class. You can freely call

```
StreamSocketSingleton instance = new StreamSocketSingleton();
instance.ConnectAsync(hostName, serviceName);
```

or if you are in your class declartion

```
this.ConnectAsync(hostName, serviceName);
```

As for this particular code I have 2 problems in it:

1. If you are really doing a singleton, your constructor should be private (i.e., no one except the singleton should be able to instance it)
2. As far as [MSDN shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket) `StreamSocket` is sealed so you can't inherit that class. Your code should not compile.

Comment: Well there goes that idea. Thanks for you help @Mario!